# CNN for MNIST with efficient sliding windows, to detect in realtime

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mnist

I want to train a CNN that can do inference in Realtime on big resolution images. The CNN must read handwritten digits consisting out of 5 digits.

So far I trained LeNet-5, Overfeat and Yolo on MNIST.

LeNet-5 gave me a good accuracy, but with a naive sliding windows approach, I ended up with 4000 windows on a FullHD image (with a big stride though), which is not fast enough. (10ms for one window on CPU->40sek per image)

So I looked into some more efficient ways for a sliding window and came across Overfeat. It convolves the whole picture and create a Class-dimensional output array [windowsX, windowsY, Classes]. The benefit here is that the overlapping regions do not have to be calculated multiple times. Right now I am trying to train and evaluate the network with the help of slim.

So finally, to my question:

**Is there a better approach or CNN for this problem?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a CRNN Model to improve the accuracy. It consists of convolution Neural Network (CNN) layers, Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) layers and a final Connectionist Temporal Classification (CTC) layer.

[CRNN Github Reference](https://github.com/bgshih/crnn)

[Building a CRNN Model](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-handwritten-text-recognition-system-using-tensorflow-2326a3487cd5)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But from I read so far, I thought R-CNN is to slow, because it only achives 5fps on GPU.